# Get expression parameter name

Tags: c#, expression, func

I need to get the name of a expression parameter. What i want to do is similar to what FluentNhibernate does with column mapping:

> Map(x => x.Name)

From this, i need "Name".

How do I do this?

I can get `x` by doing this:

```
Expression<Func<User, object>> exp = x => x.Id;
exp.Parameters[0].Name;
```

But im not able to get "Name". Note that I dont have any instance of T i can invoke on.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(expr.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name
```

As the expression returns `object`, the body will be wrapped in a Convert expression.

The following should work.

```
((expr.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression).Member.Name
```

Comment: (expr.Body as MemberExpression) returns null.

Comment: I see you updated the question. As you are returning object, there will be a Convert expression wrapping the body, will update answer.

Comment: @alexn: Only because I helped another soul out with a similar problem not a week or 2 ago :)